# crystal report in asp.net - missing parameter value

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report

I want to print my report but this error occurs. which parameters I have to define before printing? I define the printer name and parameters of PrintToPrinter function. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Missing parameter value" means that you aren't providing the report with all the parameters it needs to get the data. You must provide values for all non-optional parameters in a report for it to be able to get data.

Comment: no; the report gets loaded but when it wants to get the data from the database it is unable to as it doesn't have enough information to do so. That is the only circumstance under which I have ever seen that error. Were the parameters of the printing function incorrect you would get a different error.

Comment: I've updated MD-Tech's original answer since he's correct but I thought it could use a little more detail and example code for setting those values. I'm waiting for @MD-Tech to accept those edits.

Comment: nothing has appeared to let me accept any edits so I assume we have to wait on mods

Answer (score 3):

want to know what parameters you're missing?

```
                For Each key As ParameterField In CrystalReport.ParameterFields
                If key.HasCurrentValue = False Then
                    Debug.Print(key.Name.ToString)
                End If


            Next
```